# Display images with same specific value? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a slider for my website, but I'm a little bit stuck right now. The thing is that I don't want to use any plugin (I prefer to try to learn how to do this, and also most plugins have extra features I don't need), and the solution I thought was to retrieve all images I have uploaded to the website.

I already know how to do that, since I did it in in another website, but the problem comes when I upload images that I don't want them to be shown in the webpage. Is there any solution for this? Something like only retrieving those images with same specific value...

Thanks in advance!

PD: this is the code I'm using for retrieving all uploaded images:

```
<ul id="gallery_list">
                    <?php
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'orderby' => 'post_date',
                            'order' => 'desc',
                            'posts_per_page' => '10',
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                        );

                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() );
                        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_the_ID() );

                        echo "<li><img src='" . $image[0] . "' alt=''></li>";

                        endwhile;
                    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "images with the same value"? Also, if you want **all** images, set **'posts_per_page' => '-10'** as opposed to coming up with a possible number. **-1** literally gets all posts matching the **$args;**, 10 will get the first 10

Comment: With "value" I mean if there is something I can give those images I want to display (for example, each image has its title when uploaded to wordpress, but I don't know if wp_query can accept that as parameter to retrieve the images)

Comment: Are you confident in writing your own plugin to extend the attachment post types? You can then add a "custom field" or "tags" or whatever to the attachment posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress, attachments are just another kind of post_type--just like your query suggests. That said, there are a few ways you could go about differentiating your uploads from one another. However, WP Admin doesn't give you any ready made ways to do this. You're going to have to go beneath the hood and roll your own interface for image uploading or add a meta box to the attachments page using the Settings API.

1. Use wp_post_meta:

> a. Set a meta key/value combination when saving or updating the image:
>
> ```
> add_post_meta($post->id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
> ```
>
> b. Search by meta key/value
>
> ```
> $args = [      'post_type' => 'attachment',    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
>  'meta_value' => $meta_value
> ];
>
> $attachments = get_posts($args);
> ```

2. Create Your own Post Type:

> a. Follow the instructions here:
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types
>
> b. Search by post type.
>
> ```
> $attachments = get_posts(['post_type' => $custom_post_type_handle]);
> ```